# How to run all node.js files in some folder on startup?

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to run all node.js scripts in some folder on startup (in perfect case, running some npm script (I think the thing I run by `npm run someScript` by this) in all folders in some specific folder). Is this possible without making some Java program?
THX

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a process manager such as pm2. [PM2 - Home](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

You can set up everything that you want running on startup by following this guide [PM2 - Startup Script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)

Basically, what this startup script will do is take a currently running environment (whatever you want the startup script to do) and take a snapshot of it that it will reference on reboot.

Comment: But it doesn't look as it can start all node.js apps on startup without configuring each app.

Comment: It can start up multiple apps at the same time (I use it to start four websites in case of a server crash) In order to have multiple different apps, you will need to give them their own names. I would recommend using a ecosystem.config.js file (https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) In which you can give each app its own name and easily start them up by using ```$ pm2 start ecosystem.config.js```

Comment: Ok, but my goal is to just put the app in some folder and it will run on reboot without doing anything else.